# Interpret data from Google Analytics (queries)

Tags: google-analytics, query-string

I have this data in my Google Analytics > acquisition > search engine optimization > queries:

[image: picture for my query]

I don't really understand how to interpret it.

1. What does it mean the writing under the big numbers? For example at Clicks it is written 251 and under it smaller it is written % of Total: 125% (200)
2. Average position it is shown 64 for keywords "erasmus plus" but when I search from a computer that I did not use before and without an account to see my position in Google for "erasmus plus" keywords I am on the first page. How is it possible?